# How can I access performancedata which i can access with transaction ST03N via OData interface?

Tags: sql, odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am currently working on an SAP Gateway based on SAPUI5 to build a maintenance cockpit for a large warehouse management system. I need to access some KPIs via OData. At one point I can not go any further: how can I access the response times, which I can see in the transaction ST03N, with OData or SQL. I can not find a database table in which this information is stored.

I really do appreciate your help.

Felix